# What's the point of mapTo in RxJs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm reading the [docs for `mapTo`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mapTo) and I'm simply not getting the point of that operator's existence. I get what it does but the two line below should produce equivalent result.

```
const outcome = "bzzz";
const result1 = source.map(a => outcome);
const result2 = source.mapTo(outcome);
```

Yet, the creators of RxJs chose to increase complexity by adding an extra method. It seems pointless as such, so I'm suspecting there's more to it than what meets the eye.

What's the point of having a dedicated operator for such a specific case?

Comment: There isn't anything more to it than meets the eye; it's just shorthand. As far as *why* you'd have to ask them.

Comment: @DaveNewton That's a surprise. There's no mentioning of its status as convenience method or shorthand, so, naturally, I assumed there was some magic to it, like performance or something like that. But given your comment, it's a bit of disappointment.   :)

Comment: There's certainly some optimisation possibilities when you know that you're mapping to a constant value. I can't tell though whether these are actually implemented, or even planned. Did you take a look at the implementation yourself?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/mapTo.ts source] sums it up; I mean technically I suppose it's fractionally faster since it doesn't increment the index :shrug: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/map.ts

Comment: The function in `map` is executed on each value emission while `mapTo` argument is calculated once when the operator is created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The differences between `map` and `mapTo`

- [`map` source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L45)
- [`mapTo` source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/mapTo.ts#L39)

At first sight, we can see that `map` accepts a **callback function**

```js
function map<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg?: any)
```

whereas `mapTo` accepts a **static value**

```js
function mapTo<R>(value: R)
```

So, a clear difference is that `map`'s callback function can generate a value depending on the arguments provided. This is not the case for `mapTo`, where you just simply provide a value that will be always passed along to the next subscriber in the chain. If you will, `mapTo(value)` can be though of as

```js
map(() => value)
```

We can also deduce this from the source code:

```js
// `mapTo`
() => subscriber.next(value)

// `map`; `project` is the provided callback function
() => subscriber.next(project.call(thisArg, value, index++));
```

But you might not want to do that, why call a function when you can directly use a value?

### Some use cases

A use case might be when you have a NgRx effect and you want to return the same, non-dynamic, action, when something happens.

```js
createEffect(
  () => this.actions.pipe(
    /* some logic here... */
    mapTo(staticAction('a message here')),
  )
);
```

Another one, which might not seem very practical, is when you want to simulate some requests coming in:

```js
merge(
  timer(300).pipe(mapTo("req#1")),
  timer(600).pipe(mapTo("req#2")),
  timer(100).pipe(mapTo("req#3")),
  timer(900).pipe(mapTo("req#4")),
).pipe(
  /* some complicated logic here... */
)
```

Anyway, the point of this operator is, at least from my perspective, to indicate that you want to pass along static values, thus values that are not dependent on data from the previous subscriber.

Comment: Ridiculously well explained and exemplified. Thanks, mate. +1 och green check, of course.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Maybe the RxJS team should read this before continuing with deprecating it in version 9 :-(

Answer (score 5):

`mapTo` is really just a convenience for a specific mapping scenario where:

1. The output does not depend on emission from the source observable
2. The output will always be the same static value

The second point is important to note, because if the target value changes over time, there will be differences in the output between `map(a => target)` and `mapTo(target)`:

- `map(a => outcome)` - will return the current value of 'outcome' (*possibly different results*)
- `mapTo(outcome)` - will return the first emitted value of 'outcome' (*same result every time*)

```
let outcome = 0;
// change 'outcome' every second
interval(1000).pipe(tap(n => outcome = n * 2)).subscribe();

const source = interval(1000).pipe(take(4));

source.pipe(map(a => outcome));  // 0, 2, 4, 6
source.pipe(mapTo(outcome));     // 0, 0, 0, 0
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66908485?file=index.ts)

Comment: `outcomeFn()` equals value `0`, I believe it's never the question.

Comment: It starts with `0`, but changes every every second.  The example was just to show that there can be differences between the two.  Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66908485?file=index.ts) that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: You'd better simply call it `source.pipe(mapTo(0));` I believe OP never question that.

Comment: to be more clear , OP is **not** confuse a lambda and a function result. (aka lambda statement `a => outcomeFn()` and function call `outcomeFn()`)

Comment: btw, the first statement can be simplified to `source.pipe(map(outcomeFn))`

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but this isn't really a difference in behavior; in `mapTo` the results of calling the function are passed to `mapTo`, so it's `0` as expected. In `map` it's called on each item, same as if you did `map(outcomeFn)`, but that's an explicitly different thing.

Comment: Thank you @apple-apple! You've made me realize I gave a poor example. I was trying to point out that a value that changes over time will not be output mapTo, but will by map.  I've updated the example. :-)

Comment: I used `const` on purpose to indicate that the value doesn't change. I intended not to create magic numbers by `mapTo('x')` and `map(_=>'x')`, namely. But I can imagine that there's certain protection against unintended bugs for sloppy coders. I was definitely expecting more depth than that from a separate operator. Good example of a gotcha, though, with the change not always being propagated, so I'll +1.

Comment: In fact, if you prefix your answer with the clear statement that it's a convenience method only (and perhaps the link from the comments under the original question), I'll be happy to green-check it as accepted one.

Comment: @BizzyBob Did you see the suggestion above regarding the update of your answer? I'd like to finish it off and mark as accepted.